# break a while loop when detect the character 'a'

Tags: c

I have a file reader, it read a text file (csv) line by line...the method work fine..I use a string tokenizer for each ';' character... I need to break the first while loop when a line start with the character 'a'.... How I can do that ??

```
   while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL)
    {   
        if (cnt>0) {
            char *ch;
            ch = strtok(buffer, ";");
            while (ch != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", ch);
                ch = strtok(NULL, ";");
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Maxime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(buffer[0] == 'a') break;
```

Comment: +1, although `if(buffer[0] == 'a') break;` would be less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL && buffer[0] != 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking if you want out of both while loops do this

```
while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL)
{   
bool okToExit = false;
    if (cnt>0) {
        char *ch;
        ch = strtok(buffer, ";");
        while (ch != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", ch);
            ch = strtok(NULL, ";");
            if(buffer[0] == 'a'){
                okToExit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
if(okToExit) break;

}
```